# R - Interpreting the multinom output using the iris dataset

Tags: r, multinomial-distribution

I got a simple question.
I built a prediction model using `multinom` from the `nnet` package to predict the species of the flowers from the iris dataset. However, when I look at the output of the model, it shows the coefficients of `versicolor` and `virginica`, but not for `setosa` (check the picture). So my question is, where is the information related to the `setosa` type? Am I missing something? Or if there something I am not seeing?

This is my code.

```
   index <- sample(2, nrow(iris), replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.7, 0.3))
   train.data <- iris[index == 1, ]
   test.data <- iris[index == 2, ]
   multinom.model <- multinom(Species ~ ., data = train.data)
   print(multinom.model)
```

And this is the output of the previous line.

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same question using statsmodels.
I've found the explanation (for SPSS but it's the same answer for R or Statsmodels) [here](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/output/mlogit.htm).

> These are the estimated multinomial logistic regression coefficients for the models. An important feature of the multinomial logit model is that it estimates k-1 models, where k is the number of levels of the outcome variable. In this instance, SPSS is treating the vanilla as the referent group and therefore estimated a model for chocolate relative to vanilla  and a model for strawberry relative to vanilla. Therefore, since the parameter estimates are relative to the referent group, the standard interpretation of the multinomial logit is that for a unit change in the predictor variable, the logit of outcome m relative to the referent group is expected to change by its respective parameter estimate (which is in log-odds units) given the variables in the model are held constant.

Answer (score 1):

Setosa is being used as your reference level. In a multinomial regression model, one of the outcome levels is used as a reference to compare the other possible outcomes. Think of binary logistic regression where, for example with a mortality variable, you might be trying to find what predicts the odds of dying **compared** to staying alive, which is the default reference level.

In your model, the coefficient for petal width for the versicolor outcome could be interpreted as:
"For every unit increase in petal width, the odds of being versicolor compared to setosa are 0.407 (exp[-0.899263]) times lower."